# std::initializer_list without cbegin()/cend()

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, initializer-list

If elements in `std::initializer_list` are always const values, why we have template method like `begin()/end()` and not `cbegin()/cend()`? This names (by conventions, comparing to e.g. `std::vector`) could suggest that both `std::initializer_list` method could return `iterator`, when they always return `const_iterator`.

Comment: A good question. Well done.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hey beauty, nice to meet you here :-)

Comment: @Des1gnWizard: This isn't a dating site, thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit   _ _.... Ok you are right... _ _....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While I can't provide an insight on the reason why `cbegin()` and `cend()` are not part of `std::initializer_list`'s interface *in addition to* `begin()` and `end()`, there are certainly good reasons why the last two member functions ought to be there.

One reason is, for instance, that the range-based `for` loop is defined by the C++11 Standard precisely in terms of functions `begin()` and `end()` (Paragraph 6.5.4/1). Therefore, in order to make it possible to use it with initializer lists, `std::initializer_list` has to provide the `begin()` and `end()` member functions:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto l = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for (int x : l) // Works because std::initializer_list provides
                    // the member functions begin() and end().
    {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
}
```

Moreover, it makes sense to consider that member functions `cbegin()` and `cend()` were not present before C++11: therefore, having `begin()` and `end()` on the interface of `std::initializer_list`allows making old generic algorithms written in terms of `begin()` and `end()` work with initializer lists as well, without requiring them to be rewritten.

You write:

> These names (by conventions, comparing to e.g. `std::vector`) could suggest that both `std::initializer_list` method could return `iterator`, when they always return `const_iterator`.

Actually, this analogy is not very appropriate. `std::vector`'s function `begin()`, for instance, returns an `iterator` when invoked on a non-`const` instance of `std::vector` (i.e. a mutable one, whose elements can be modified, added, and removed), and a `const_iterator` when invoked on a `const` instance (i.e. an immutable one, whose content cannot be altered):

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    // A non-const vector...
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto i = v.begin();
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<decltype(i), decltype(v)::iterator>::value, 
        //                                     ^^^^^^^^
        //                                     ...non-const iterator!
        "What?");

    // A const vector...
    std::vector<int> const vc = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    auto ic = vc.begin();
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<decltype(ic), decltype(vc)::const_iterator>::value,
        //                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //                                       ...const iterator!
        "What?");
}
```

Initializer lists are immutable collections by definition. Per Paragraph 18.9/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> An object of type `initializer_list<E>` provides access to an array of objects of type `const E`. [...]

Since initializer lists are collections of `const` elements, the `cbegin()` and `cend()` functions would actually do the exact same thing that `begin()` and `end()` do.

In fact, `iterator` and `const_iterator` are both defined as pointers to constant elements of the initializer list's value type, so it's arguable whether it is the case that `begin()` and `end()` always return `const_iterator` (as you assume), or whether they always return `iterator`.

This is how Paragraph 18.9/1 of the C++11 Standard defines the `initializer_list` class template:

```
namespace std {
    template<class E> class initializer_list {
    public:
        typedef E value_type;
        // ...
        typedef const E* iterator;
        typedef const E* const_iterator;
        // ...
        constexpr const E* begin() const noexcept; // first element
        constexpr const E* end() const noexcept; // one past the last element
    };

    // ...
}
```